# Why local_db.bin doesn't create by GAE?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, intellij-idea, google-cloud-datastore

I was using GAE 1.8.8 and application was working fine. For improvement I needed to change my entity class. I found the simplest way on local machine is deleting local_db.bin file directly from `out/artifacts/AppEngine_war_exploded/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/local_db.bin`. So I did it and whenever I ran the project, GAE created new one for me.

Have no idea what happened and GAE doesn't create  anymore :(
I upgraded GAE to 1.8.9 today and still have same problem. Also when I open `http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/datastore` page it doesn't show any thing. 
[image]

When I run the app, it always display following message and never create local_db.bin:

```
Jan 28, 2014 11:41:07 PM com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService init
INFO: Local Datastore initialized: 
    Type: High Replication
    Storage: /Users/hesam/Desktop/hesam/workspace/EyeBall/AppEngine/out/artifacts/AppEngine_war_exploded/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/local_db.bin
Jan 28, 2014 11:41:07 PM com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService load
INFO: The backing store, /Users/hesam/Desktop/hesam/workspace/EyeBall/AppEngine/out/artifacts/AppEngine_war_exploded/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/local_db.bin, does not exist. It will be created.
```

I'm suspicious to application type. Should it be set on `Web Application: exploded`?
[image]

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Moved comment into an answer below

Comment: Thanks. so do you have any idea why GAE doesn't generate local db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exploded in this context means "not compressed". This is normal with the GAE SDK. It will create the local_db.bin file only after you write some data.

Comment: Thanks martin. Agree but the problem is I'm writing to datastore and app runs okay but local db doesn't create. please look at my other topic regard this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379265/gae-local-datastore-does-not-create

Comment: If you're writing data on the development server and reading it back again then local_db.bin probably exists but maybe not in the directory where you expect to find it.  Try a system wide file search.

Comment: I had mistake in my code. After problem fixed local db created. Those how want to know what was problem can refer to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21379265/513413